# List of deque of integers java

Tags: java, list, deque

this is my SSCCE

http://pastebin.com/rABzKgAx

http://pastebin.com/SypQxApe

Im trying to work with datastructure List of Deque of Integer.

So i add few integers to the deque, then add it to the finalList, but since i manipulate further with Deque and remove elements it also removes these elements from the finalList. So how am i supposed to save these items to the list ? Becuase for example, i add 30 elements to the finalList, but since i am removing the original item from Deque i simply have 30 empty elements in finalList:/. You can read the rest from the code, and on the line 57 there is a output on stdout, ant it returns empty string, so there you can see the problem.

So the problem is that i copy only reference to the object, not the object, so how am i supposed to copy object ?

Comment: Please paste your code to provide any suggestions.

Comment: -1 for posting code off site. Put a small extract in the question explaining the problem.

Comment: Yea, sorry for that, but i find posting code snippets on this site really uncomfortable, since there is no actual code tag, just intendation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is where using a debugger is helpful.

You are using

```
finalList.add(tokens);
```

and assuming you have added a copy of the list, but you are only adding a copy of the reference to the list.

So

```
            tokens.add(token);
            Func(places, index+1, tokens);
            tokens.removeLast();
```

removes every element it adds, and the list is empty.

It appears what you intended was

```
        finalList.add(new LinkedList<Integer>(tokens));
```

Comment: I know where the problem is, but i dont know how to solve it.

Comment: In that case it would have been helpful to add this to the question. The solution is to only add a copy.

Comment: BTW: `Func` doesn't return anything.

Comment: Yea, i know, i just forget to change the description, actually, the reurn value is going to be stored in finalList

Answer (score 1):

`final` only means that the variable cannot be changed to point to another list later, it does not mean that the list cannot be changed. If you need the original list, you have to copy it before changing it.

Comment: Okay, but how do i copy objects ?

Comment: for lists you can use the `clone` method.